# How do I convert FLIC files properly

Tags: uti

I need to open and convert old Autodesk Animator FLIC (.FLI) files (from MS DOS) into something more useful, like say AVI or even an image sequence. I realize both Motion and QuickTime "can" do this, but they mess up the films, probably because of a faulty decoder.

I've already downloaded the UNIX app xnview, but it doesn't work well. While it can handle the format well, it can only store one frame at a time as a standalone picture, which is PAINFUL to do when there are usually several hundred frames in any given animation.

Comment: You would be better asking this on http://avp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the command line tool [ppm2fli](http://vento.pi.tu-berlin.de/STROEMUNGSAKUSTIK/SOFTWARE/ppm2fli/main.html) which includes [unflick](http://vento.pi.tu-berlin.de/STROEMUNGSAKUSTIK/SOFTWARE/ppm2fli/unflick.1.html)?

**DESCRIPTION**

> The program unflick extracts single images or a series of images from
>   a given FLI-animation. The extracted images are stored in separated
>   files. The formats PPM (raw and ascii) and FBM (mapped 8bpp) are
>   available. Additionally unflick can call an external filter program to
>   convert the output in another file format. The file animation contains
>   the input FLI-animation. The output file names are controlled by the
>   parameters base and extension...

Comment: Hm, these progs need to be compiled for my system. Never done that before, but... Downloaded Xcode (4 fricking gigs) to my Mac and tried GCC to no avail. Get funny errors complaining about x86_64 and an 'undefined symbols: "_main"'... Not being a C-programmer, I don't have a clue about this.

Comment: Download the source, move it somewhere handy (~/src/ would be a good choice, ~ being your home folder) unzip it. Launch Terminal (Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal), navigate to that folder (`cd src/ppm2fli-2.1/`), then `make`, then `sudo cp unflick /usr/local/bin` (type your password + enter when prompted), then `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/unflick`. Now in Terminal, type `unflick`, you should see: `UNFLICK version 1.1c by Klaus Ehrenfried (C) 1995,2002
` The [man page for unflick](http://vento.pi.tu-berlin.de/STROEMUNGSAKUSTIK/SOFTWARE/ppm2fli/unflick.1.html) should supply the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you can do about converting the files....   However, if xnview will export the still frames to a folder, and if the files are sequentially numbered, QuickTime will be able to make a movie out of these images.

Perhaps xnview can be scripted to export all of the still frames.

Will that work for you?

Comment: Yes, that will work, but how do you script xnview?